How to use Fragment class in compose
i am working with a third party library for rendering the epub content it exposes a fragment that can be created using a factory method but as i am working in compose with very little knowledge of fragments .
i did saw the documentation on androidviewbinding composable but i guess i need to create some xml for that
so as i was searching for another solution i came across a composable AndroidFragment which recently became stable what i did is created a seperate fragment to instantiate the required fragment
class EpubNavigatorAdapter : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var factory: FragmentFactory
        private lateinit var className: String
        @OptIn(ExperimentalReadiumApi::class)
        fun initialize(
            publication: Publication,
            initialLocator: Locator?,
            readingOrder: List<Link>? = null,
            initialPreferences: EpubPreferences = EpubPreferences(),
            listener: EpubNavigatorFragment.Listener? = null,
            paginationListener: EpubNavigatorFragment.PaginationListener? = null,
            configuration: EpubNavigatorFragment.Configuration = EpubNavigatorFragment.Configuration()
        ) {
            val epubNavigatorFactory = EpubNavigatorFactory(publication)
            factory = epubNavigatorFactory.createFragmentFactory(
                initialLocator,
                readingOrder,
                initialPreferences,
                listener,
                paginationListener,
                configuration
            )
            className = EpubNavigatorFragment::class.java.name
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val navigatorFragment = factory.instantiate(requireContext().classLoader, className)
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, navigatorFragment)
            .commit()
    }
}

   AndroidFragment<EpubNavigatorAdapter>(fragmentState = fragmentState)
i did call the initliaze before calling the AndroidFragment composable but still facing erros which are too complex to understand
example there was some activity error because my main activity inherited the ComponentActivity rather than AppCompatActivity, now facing some theme errors and for the said composable i didn't found any example so it's getting trickier for me
i am not asking how to solve those error code as solving one leads to another rather an easier approach or an article that might help as this is my first app so i don't want to over complicate things

If you want to add fragment support to ComponentActivity, is there a reason you aren't using FragmentActivity? That's just ComponentActivity with fragment support and without the theming stuff that AppCompatActivity requries. Please include the full stack trace of the error if you're still having an error with FragmentActivity.

@ianhanniballake oh i didn't knew it thanks , actually the issue was the attempt of retrieving the fragment manager while my MainActivity  inherits ComponentActivity rather than the AppCompatActivity i did fixed that which led to another error setting the theme in manifest according to AppCompatActivity but after that i ran into another error
i don't want solution to these errors but a approach how to integerate with an example or  an blog /article explaining it i find it tough because most of the blog that i read focuses on adding fragment which have a xml layout
